# El programa se salta una parte del codigo

Tags: java

estoy desarrollando un programa que posee un sistema de inventario por archivos en el cual, ademas de almacenar datos con caracteristicas, tambien se pueden realizar procesos de compras.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que a la hora de seleccionar el id del producto que se desea comprar el ciclo for que identifica la linea del arraylist queda totalmente ignorado y por tanto, el programa solo me pregunta si se desea realizar otra compra, que seria la accion que se ejecuta luego del ciclo for.

```
 public void compra(){
         Inventario_Final inf = new Inventario_Final(); 
         //variables
                int cant;
                int contador = 0;

                //Proceso
                while(sys == false){

                inf.MostrarObjeto();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Selecione el id del objeto que desea comprar: ");
                int pro = sc.nextInt();


                for(Inventario_Final n:obj){
                    if(n.getId() == pro){
                        do{
                        System.out.print("Cuantos "+n.getNombre()+" desea llevar?: ");
                        cant = sc.nextInt();

                        contador = contador + cant;

                        if(cant > n.getCantidad()){
                            System.out.println("Cantidad invalida.");
                        }
                        //ejecucion de las variables precios    
                        precio = precio + (n.getPrecio()*cant); 
                        precioIva = (precio*0.16)+precio;
                        precioBol = precio * 75000;
                        preciototal = precioIva + preciototal;

                        sys = true;
                        }while(sys == false);

                    }
                }

                String resp;
                System.out.print("Desea seguir comprando? y/n: ");
                resp = sc.next();

                if(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    inf.Factura(precio, precioIva, precioBol, contador); //Mandar los valores al constructor
                    inf.Menu();
                    }else{sys = false;}
                }
     }
```

Comment: En tu ciclo for a qué hace referencia la variable 'obj'?

Comment: Hace referencia a un arraylist

Comment: Imagino que obj es el arrayList agrega por favor como lo llenas. @RicardoAraujoChacín

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El hecho por el cual tu programa no permita definir cuantos productos deseas llevar y todo lo que indica que bloque, se debe a  que el ArrayList `obj` no contiene elementos. Puedes imprimir su medida para que verifiques esta información.

```
           ...
           ...

           System.out.println("Elementos en arraylist : " + obj.size());

           for(Inventario_Final n:obj){
             ...
             ...
           }
            ...
            ...
```

Asegura que tu ArrayList obj contenga elementos para que pueda realizar la iteración.

Comment: Acabo de probar hacer lo que has comentado, efectivamente no esta reconociendo los elementos del arraylist, voy a ponerme a trabajar en ello